# Rear bike stand: 2 points of contact vs 1

Tags: kickstand

When choosing a rear bike stand, does it make any difference that it clamps to 1 or 2 tubes of the chassis?

[image: Chainstay-clamped kickstand]

[image: Chainstay- and seatstay-clamped kickstand]

My bike is sometimes parked with rear paniers.

Comment: Are there any pictures of the double model mounted to a bike?

Comment: sadly no pictures on the dealer site

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A single-tube clamp has to be fairly tight to prevent rotation, especially if the bike is heavily/unevenly loaded.  A double-tube clamp doesn't have to be as tight.  Whether this is enough to allow you to use the double-tube version on fragile materials is another matter.

The fit of the double version has to be much more precise. With some frames it just won't work.  I wouldn't be confident about getting it to fit with rear disk brakes.